# How does a website know what salt to use when you try to login

Tags: hash, salt

For example let's say my password is **"foo"** and the website is using a md5 hash on passwords with a unique salt appended to it.

So when I register my password will be stored as **"foo"** with a salt appended to it and then md5 hashed.

Then when I send a login request the website will append a salt to **"foo"** and then md5 hash it, but how will the website know what the correct unique salt to use is?

How will the website **magically** know the **correct unique salt** to append to my password which is then md5 hashed, to verify the password **I entered** is equal to the md5 hashed salted password in the database?

Comment: The recommended practice is to store the salt right next to the password in the database, or with some libraries, the salt is part of the hash string (appended to it) that is stored in the hashed password field. Looks something like {version}${hash}${salt}

Comment: @mukunda Okay but let's say in a database it stores my md5 hashed salted password and then in the next column it stores the unique_salt. When a user goes to login , the user will enter password **'foo'**, in order to properly verify the password is correct it needs to append that same **'unique_salt'** stored in the database and then md5 hash it. My question is how does the website find out this correct **'unique_salt'** when somebody is trying to log in. Does it query the database with the row that contains the email entered and then grabs the unique_salt column or something else?

Comment: When setting the password, a salt is generated, appended to the password, its hashed, and the hash and salt are saved. When they log in again, that same salt is fetched from the database (linked to their user ID/email), appended to the password, it's hashed, and then tested against the stored hash.

Comment: @mukunda Thank you :) I see now how this unique salt is obtained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual process of handling passwords:

1. User registers with a password.
2. A new data record is created for their user ID (which can come in the form of username or email, etc.)
3. Their password is handled:

   1. A salt is generated for them, and that salt is saved in the data record. It's very common and recommended that the salt is visible right next to the password hash.
   2. The password is combined with the salt (typically a library handles even this step for you, as any little nuance like appending salt matters a lot in security).
   3. The password is hashed using a function designed for password hashing. This is usually quite computationally expensive to frustrate brute force attempts.
   4. The password hash is stored in the data record, and the original password is discarded.

Then when they log in, there's no magic here:

1. The data record is looked up using their user ID.
2. The password they give is combined with the salt from the data record and then hashed.
3. If it matches the hash stored, they are granted access.

Some notes:

- Password hashing is expensive. I don't think it's uncommon for it to take more than 1 whole second of computing time. Imagine the processing load if a thousand people are logging in at once.
- A lot of things can go wrong if you aren't using a decent library to handle password hashing. Writing any of the steps yourself is not recommended.
- It's common for libraries to output a coded string that contains everything you need to verify against a password, such as a version code, the hash, and the salt used.

Comment: +1. You might also mention that the recommended format for such coded strings is the PHC string format (a recently standardized format almost indistinguishable from ascii modular crypt format).